# Why do I have additional addresses in my address link?

Tags: asp.net, web, webaddress

I am working on a website and when I open the first page I receive additions to the address link.
For example I should have : `www.rpcmap.com/` but actually I am having this link:

`www.rpcmap.com/(S(japkjl0zot2rvmfc0v104b0j))/default.aspx`
Does anyone know the reason of these additional links?
 You can access the website [here](http://www.rpcmap.com/)

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: nice site...any url rewriting concept u used?

Comment: I am sorry but what do you mean about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a 100% up to speed with .NET but I can almost venture a guess that it's session/state info being injected by your web.config's URL re-write.

First port of call would be to open your web.config and see why it's injecting the session info - and either hide it or remove it.

Please note - purely a guess!

Comment: anytime! Awesome site btw. Just if I may add two more cents?

you have "/Styles/images/info_image1.png" which is slowing down the site terribly (834kb!!) - export it as a jpg and reduce it's physical size - currently you only us it in your info segment.